# Vorläufer für "Wer traut sich jetzt noch Präsident?"

Tags: etymology, sentence-structure

In der heutigen Heute-Sendung um 19:00 Uhr und der anschließenden Diskussionsrunde wurde gefragt:

"Wer traut sich jetzt noch Präsident?"

d.h., das "… zu werden" wurde verschluckt, bzw. Präsident wird wie ein Verb im Infinitiv behandelt "Wer traut sich (angesichts der Krokodile) zu schwimmen". Ein Versehen ist ausgeschlossen – der Titel der Maybrit-Illner-Sendung trägt den Satz als Untertitel im elektronischen Programmführer und auch im Videotext.

Bereits in Bundestagswahlkämpfen wurde gefragt: "Wer kann Kanzler", so dass man sich fragen könnte "Wer kann Deutschlehrer" – ich will jedoch wissen, ob dies die erste Missgestaltung dieser Art war, oder ob dem ein Schlager, ein Werbespruch oder eine andere, populär gewordene Wendung gleicher Bauart vorausging.

Eine wörtliche Übersetzung eines englischen Satzbaus erkenne ich nicht, frage mich aber, ob es in der Jugendsprache vielleicht zuerst hip war, so zu verkürzen.

Muss man befürchten, dass über die häufige Verwendung dies ebenso zur Regel wird wie das Verschwinden des Genitivs?

Die eigentliche Frage ist aber die erste: Was ist die Urform dieses Musters?

Comment: Du bist nicht allein: http://udall.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/subjekt-pradikat-objekt-oder-so/ - https://plus.google.com/107223467325602754395/posts

Comment: @JohnSmithers this made my day: "Ich sollte beschließen, meine Sätze auch nicht mehr vollständig und schon gar nicht zu Ende!"

Comment: Auch in der Literatur gibt es was ähnliches: "Dem Tod die Toten." von Frank Schätzing: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dative-in-this-sentence-dem-tod-die-toten

Comment: @hmundt: Welches Verb ist hier verschluckt?

Comment: @user unknown: "Lass…" (Imperativ) oder "…gehören…" könnte hier verschluckt…

Comment: Ja, das Verb steht an anderer Stelle - ein verschlucktes Verb sehe ich auch, aber dass der Buchtitel Pate gestanden haben könnte bei der Formulierung glaube ich nicht. Dafür sind sie doch zu weit auseinander.

Comment: Dazu fällt mir nur "Ich mach dich Krankenhaus" ein.

Comment: @Em1: Hey!  Selbstbezügliche Sätze sind was für Sprachgourmets ;D

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard: "Ich mach dich Krankenhaus" ist aber doch Prollsprache. Welchen Gefallen sollte die Heuteredaktion daran finden, sowas zu benutzen - was will sie damit ausdrücken? Jugendlichkeit? Es ist auch in Nachrichtensendungen nicht gang und gäbe. Nur bei Kanzlerschaft und jetzt beim Bundespräsidenten. Gab es vielleicht eine Berufscastingshow im Fernsehen: "Ich kann Rockstar" oder sowas?

Comment: @Loong: Wenn man bei mehrteiligen Abkürzungen Blanks setzt, dann kann das Layout die Zeile zwischen den Teilen umbrechen. Dies könnte man nur durch aufwendige HTML-Gymnastik vermeiden. Da ist es praktischer die Blanks zu eliminieren - lesbar ist auch ein z.B. oder d.h. Ähnlich setze ich keine typografischen Anführungsstriche. Viel entbehrlicher Aufwand.

Comment: Ich glaube, das Konstrukt geht höchstens bedingt auf die stark alliterative Phrase _kann Kanzler_ zurück. Viel mehr sind Formen von _sein_ bzw. _werden_ in vielen Sprachen Kandidaten dafür, in einer Ellipse zu verschwinden. Möglicherweise liegt der Grund eher darin, dass Verben produktiv als Infinitiv substantiviert werden: _Wer traut sich zu kochen? Wer traut sich das Kochen (zu)? Wer traut sich kochen/Kochen?_ Das könnte dann auf andere, originäre Substantive übertragen worden sein.

Comment: Wir sind Papst!

Comment: @user unknown: Bei einer mehrteiligen Abkürzung muss im Deutschen ein Leerzeichen stehen, was man insbesondere in diesem Forum auch richtig machen sollte. Ich hatte ein geschütztes Leerzeichen verwendet, was beim Zeilenumbruch nicht getrennt wird.

Comment: _Wer traut sich, Koch zu sein? Wer traut sich Koch?_

Comment: Du schreibst: »Muss man **befürchten**, dass über die häufige Verwendung dies ebenso zur Regel wird...«. Warum »*befürchten*«? Wenn es häufig verwendet wird, wird es zur Regel. Das ist so. Aber das nimmt keine Arbeitsplätze weg, macht niemanden krank und verschlechtert auch nicht das Wetter. Warum also sich vor Veränderungen im Gebrauch der Sprache fürchten? Sprache lebt, und Leben ist Veränderung. Menschen verursachen diese Veränderungen, und Menschen haben auch die Wahl sich an diese Veränderungen anzupassen oder verbittert (und ohne Aussicht auf Erfolg) dagegen zu kämpfen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Sowas wird zur Marotte und verläuft sich dann auch wieder, und wenn später jemand in alten Texten drauf stößt wird er es für einen technischen Fehler halten. Schön ist das nicht. Und der Lebendigkeit d. Sprache per se wie einem Fetisch zu huldigen überzeugt mich auch nicht. Zu sterben ist auch eine Veränderung.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es klang zwar in der Frage und in manchen Kommentaren schon an, aber eben auch nicht mehr: zumindest was den Sprachgebrauch der Berliner Politik (und der darüber berichtenden Medien) betrifft, geht das Muster auf Franz Müntefering zurück.

Dieser sagte in einem [Interview mit dem "Tagesspiegel"](http://www.tagesspiegel.de/politik/die-spd-muss-voranmachen/704498.html) im April 2006 über den damaligen SPD-Vorsitzenden Kurt Beck:

> Dass er ein guter Mann ist, **der Kanzler kann**, ist ganz klar.

2009 äußerte er sich offenbar in ähnlicher Weise über Frank-Walter Steinmeier. Da hatte das ZDF die Formulierung aber schon aufgegriffen für seine Casting-Show ["Ich kann Kanzler!"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ich_kann_Kanzler!) (2012 neu aufgelegt), und das Wort war in aller Munde, wie man an [diesem Artikel aus der Main-Post](http://www.mainpost.de/ueberregional/politik/main-posttitelseite/Unterm-Strich-Wer-kann-Kanzler;art9484,5174329) oder [diesem aus der Süddeutschen Zeitung](http://sz-magazin.sueddeutsche.de/texte/anzeigen/29579/) sehen kann.

Ob Müntefering in dem Interview bewußt oder unbewußt selbst auf Vorlagen für diese Formulierung zurückgegriffen hat, kann ich nicht sagen.

"Wer traut sich jetzt noch Präsident?" verstehe ich als Anspielung des ZDF (mit leicht selbst-ironischem Unterton) auf dieses geflügelte Wort. Es ging nun nicht mehr darum, wie bei der Kanzlerfrage, wer sich bzw. wem man zutraut, das Amt auszuüben und es auszufüllen, sondern darum, wer es (unter den damaligen Umständen) überhaupt wagt, das Amt des Bundespräsidenten anzustreben.

Müntefering wiederum bezog sich in dem Interview auf eine Zeile in einem [Lied der "Ärzte"](http://www.die-beste-band-der-welt.de/texte/debil/zu_spaet.htm) aus den 80ern:

> Ich wußte nicht, daß er auch Karate kann.

;-)

Wenn wir den Spaß mal beiseite lassen, so fällt doch auf, daß es im Bereich Sport/Spiel/Tanz  einige Substantive gibt, die keine substantivierten Verben sind, die aber vor allem umgangssprachlich zusammen mit "können" verwendet werden, um auszudrücken, daß man die entsprechenden Fertigkeiten besitzt. Nach dem gleichen Muster kann man auch ausdrücken, eine Sprache zu beherrschen. Ich vermute, daß das schon recht lange so praktiziert wird. Es funktioniert auch recht unauffällig nach dem Prinzip der Ellipse, denn die fehlenden Verben liegen mehr oder minder auf der Hand:

> Ich kann Skat [spielen].
>   Kannst Du Cha-Cha [tanzen]?
>   Der kann Karate [kämpfen? boxen?].
>   Sie kann Englisch [sprechen, verstehen, lesen, schreiben].

Ich könnte mir vorstellen, daß Müntefering solche Wendungen im Ohr hatte, als er zum ersten Mal davon sprach, daß jemand "Kanzler" könne. Die Adaption entbehrt nicht einer gewissen Nonchalance (und wurde vielleicht gerade deshalb so populär): zum einen ist nun auf einmal gar nicht klar, welches Verb in der Ellipse fehlt. Werden? Das Amt ausüben können (was ja wiederum ein ganzes Bündel von Fähigkeiten umfaßt)? Egal - er kann es jedenfalls (so der entstehende Eindruck). Zum anderen rückt er damit die Amtsausübung sprachlich in die Nähe einer Sportart oder eines Spiels, also in eine dem Publikum vertraute und an Stammtischen und ähnlichen Orten sehr oft anzutreffende Domäne. Das geschieht aber sehr subtil - die Formulierung klingt irgendwie fremd (und für die sensibleren Ohren falsch) und bleibt dadurch hängen, zugleich aber doch vertraut (ohne daß man sofort merken müßte, woher) und verständlich.

Comment: Interessant bleibt, ob der Satz auf eine frühere, vielleicht legitime Form außerhalb der Politik zurückgeht. Die Antwort "I can Boogie" wurde inzwischen gelöscht.

Comment: @userunknown Ich hab bei der gelöschten Antwort zwar nicht verstanden, warum gerade ein englischer Liedtext Wurzel einer deutschen Formulierung sein soll - aber Du hast mich auf eine Idee gebracht. Siehe mein Edit...

Comment: `zum einen ist nun auf einmal gar nicht klar, welches Verb in der Ellipse fehlt.` Spielen oder darstellen. :)

Comment: Da fallen mir noch die Schulfächer ein: Ich kann Mathematik. Ich kann Englisch.

Comment: @Georg Danke für den Hinweis. Bei Schulfächern allgemein bin ich mir nicht so sicher, wie üblich das ist. Aber bei Sprachen (und dann eben auch bezogen auf die Sprache, unabhängig vom zugehörigen Schulfach) ist das ein sehr gängiger Ausdruck. Ich hab's mit aufgenommen.

Comment: Ich komme nochmal drauf zurück. Skat, Boogie usw. sind ja Tätigkeiten, aber Kanzler ist ein Amt, keine Tätigkeit. Kanzeln sagt man nicht, jedenfalls nicht in der pol. Berichterstattung, aber präsidieren geht als Verb wohl durch. "Ich kann präsidieren" wäre für meine Ohren jedenfalls richtig, "ich kann Judoka" oder "Ich kann Tänzer" klingt aber doch genauso falsch, ebenso "Ich kann Mathematiker" usw. "Er kann regieren" ist wohl der Term, der vermieden werden sollte, weil er so autoritär klingt. Gegen die Elllipse spricht übrigens, weil offen bleibt, ob "Kanzler werden" oder "...sein" gemeint is

Answer (score 0):

Dazu gibt es im letzten Spiegel (7/2012) einen passenden [Essay: Linguist Uwe Hinrichs über den Einfluss der Migranten auf die deutsche Sprache](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-83977255.html).

Zusammengefasst: Die Sprache wandelt sich und in den letzten Jahren wandelt sie sich stärker, weil es in Deutschland viele Migranten gibt. U.a. vereinfacht sich die Grammatik.

Ausschnitt:

> Das Erste, was eine Sprache verliert ist das, was sie für einfache Kommunikationszwecke mit fremden Sprechern am allerwenigsten benötigt: Das sind die Fälle, die Endungen und die Regeln der Verknüpfung.

Comment: Gibt es denn Sprachen, aus denen das eine wörtliche Übersetzung sein könnte? Haben Journalisten so intensiven Migrantenkontakt, dass sie deren Sprache übernehmen?

Comment: Der Artikel [Kanzler muss kein Komma können](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/gesellschaft/0,1518,620535,00.html) behandelt das Thema auch am Rande, liefert aber keine Ursprungstheorie, bis auf "in enger Anlehnung an den eigenwillig stakkatohaften Münte-Sprech".

Comment: Hier fehlt übrigens keine Endung und kein Fall sondern ein Verb. Dass fehlende Sprachbestandteile die Sprache einfacher machen halte ich auch für eine Illusion. Es entstehen ja Mehrdeutigkeiten und Unklarheiten. "Ich geh Vater" - heißt das, ich gehe mit dem Vater, zu dem Vater, ich werde selbst Vater, ich gehe wie mein Vater? Von "Ich kann Kanzler" ist im Artikel auch nicht die Rede.