# Liebe muss man können

Tags: word-order

I saw today the movie [Die Welt der Wunderlichs](https://www.film.at/die-welt-der-wunderlichs-liebe-muss-man-koennen) (really weird movie, btw) and I the subheading of the movie caught my eye:

> Liebe muss man können

which I guess it is another way of saying `Man muss Liebe können`. But **what exactly is meant?**

If it had said `Man muss lieben können` with a verb, it would have made a lot more sense, but in this form, something seems out of place

**UPDATE**

I already had guesses that it is a way of saying "One has to be able to love", but it is the way of saying it that confuses me. Could I, for example, say `Lied muss man können` for singing?

Comment: I'd translate it to “you must be able to love”. Does that help?

Comment: I also guessed that is what it means. But what is this way of talking? Can I also say stuff like `Man muss Lied können` for singing?

Comment: This is simply making use of German’s free word order. There is no specific expression or anything associated with the phrase, it is *just* additional emphasis for *Liebe.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalerweise spricht man so nicht.

Liebe wird selten als Handwerk, Kunstform oder Tätigkeit verstanden.

- Radfahren muss man können.
- Backen muss man können.
- Pfannkuchen backen muss man können.
- Pfannkuchen zubereiten muss man können.
- Singen muss man können.
- Lieder singen muss man können.
- Lieder komponieren muss man können.

Die Formen mit Verb aber ohne Objekt sehen *Liebe**n** muss man können* ähnlich. Sprachlich korrekt wäre auch *Liebe machen muss man können*, bedeutete aber Liebe, im Sinne von Sex.
Die anderen Nutzungen des Hlfsverbs *können* benötigen ein Verb, was man denn können muss (Pfannkuchen auf den Punkt *backen*, oder die Zutaten *anrühren*, Lieder *Komponieren* oder *singen*?). Bei einem Untertitel eines Films fehlt hier der Kontext, um es auch so zu verstehen. *Liebe inszenieren muss man können* könnte ein sinnvoller Satz sein, oder: "In sich selbst (oder dem anderen) Liebe entfachen (oder wachhalten) muss man können."

Normalerweise versteht man Liebe als etwas, das einen überfällt, nicht etwas das man macht. Seit einigen Jahren breitet sich diese Phrase jedoch aus, zu beobachten auch bei: "[Er kann Kanzler](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/3932/266)". Ob es einen identifizierten Ursprung der Phrase gibt weiß ich nicht.

Wie c.p. in seiner Antwort verdeutlicht kann es Kontexte geben, in denen auch sie kann Lied oder Lied muss man können gesagt werden kann. Insofern muss man wohl rückschließen, dass es die Aufgabe der schrägen Formulierung ist, diesen Kontext genau aufzurufen, hier, dass Liebe nicht als Glück über einen kommt, sondern gemacht wird, sowie dass es nur ein Genre ist, welches der Könner abruft, wodurch sie als etwas Instrumentelles in den Blick gerückt wird.

Dass es Dir als befremdlich aufgefallen ist ist ein Beleg, dass Du sprachlich auf einem guten Kurs bist.

Comment: "Nur die Formen mit substantiviertem Verb sind ähnlich zu *Lieben muss man können*." - nur ist weder *lieben* in diesem Satz, noch irgendeines der Verben in deinen Beispielen substantiviert. Das wird klar, wenn man die Sätze umstellt und die Großschreibung vom Satzanfang wegfällt (*Man muss lieben können.*), aber auch in deinen Beispielen, bei denen das Verb ein Objekt mitbringt (z.B. *Pfannkuchen backen muss man können.*).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Done.

Answer (score 2):

> Man muss Lied können.

As in English language some words require an article:

> You have to be able to speak English.
>
> You have to be able to sing **the** song.

But not:

> You have to be able to **sing song**.

So the correct sentence would be (for example):

> Man muss **das** Lied können.

In the plural an article will change the meaning of the sentence:

> Man muss Lieder können.
>
> Man muss **die** Lieder können.

The first sentence says that you must be able to sing *any* songs while the second sentence says that you must be able to sing *certain specific* songs.

Normally the word `können` is used with an adjective. However in some cases it is used with a substantive.

This is often done if the substantive already describes an action so it is clear which adjective is meant:

> Man muss Gartenarbeit können.

Languages are typically used the same way (in fact nearly noone says `Englisch sprechen können`):

> Man muss Englisch können.

In other cases it normally depends on the context if the sentence is understood or not. The sentence:

> Man muss Pfannkuchen können.

... would be perfectly understood by most Germans when you are talking about cooking: You have to be able to *cook* *Pfannkuchen*. However the sentence would sound very strange when you are not explicitly talking about cooking. Maybe noone would understand it.

> Man muss das Lied können.

Would be understood by most Germans that you have to be able to sing that song; however depending on the context it might also mean that you have to be able to play that on a musical instrument.

There are two things to say about the sentence:

> Liebe muss man können

I'm not sure but I think that the grammatically correct form would be:

> **Die** Liebe muss man können

This sentence would normally not be used in "real" language. However book writers, song writers, movie producers and other artists have a lot of freedom when using language so they can "invent" sentences like this one.

I have to mention that the combination of `man`, `können` and `müssen` normaly (at least in **all** sentences written above) has two different meanings:

1. You have to be able to do something / it is necessary that you are able to do something
2. You should not do something unless you can do that very well

> Bei einer Spanienreise muss man Spanisch können.

... can therefore have one of the following two meanings:

1. It is necessary that you can speak Spanish if you are travelling to Spain.
2. If you don't speak Spanish very well you'll better talk in English when travelling to Spain.

Comment: "I'm not sure but I think that the grammatically correct form would be" - it is certainly not generally ungrammatical in German to use nouns without an article, and considering that plenty of expressions using *Liebe* without an article exist ("Es war Liebe auf den ersten Blick."; "Der Kuchen wurde mit viel Liebe und Sorgfalt zubereitet."; "Er hat es aus Liebe getan."), I am confident *Liebe* qualifies as one of the nouns that can be used without an article under certain circumstances.

Comment: Hallo Martin, kleiner Tip für deine Antworten, versuche erst eine verständliche Erklärung zu geben, die dann durch Beispiele erläutert werden kann. So ist das Ganze etwas verwirrend und man begreift den Punkt vor lauter Beispielen nicht.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Tatsache ist, dass der Artikel bei einigen Wörtern je nach Kontext verwendet wird oder nicht. Beispiel "Fußball": Man kann durchaus sagen: "*Fußball muss man können*", nicht jedoch "***Den** Fußball muss man können.*". Auf der anderen Seite würde man sagen: "*Der Sponsor hat viel für **den** Fußball getan.*", während "*Der Sponsor hat viel für Fußball getan.*" eher unüblich ist. Meiner *persönlichen* Meinung nach wäre im Beispiel "*Die Liebe*" und nicht "*Liebe*" richtig - das kann aber auch falsch sein.

Answer (score 2):

*This answer partially overlaps with [Martin's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/32905/5999), but I wanted to offer an alternative and somewhat orthogonal approach at explaining the expression.*

There are three parts to this topic, and accordingly, I am going to structure this answer in three sections.

---

The German verb *können* can be used with every German verb, such as

> Man muss lieben können.

This means

> One has to be able to love.

However, *können* can also be used with nouns that express a skill, or, in general, something that can be practised and learned. Notably, this is used to express mastery of foreign languages:

> Sie kann Russisch.

This is synonymous to

> Sie kann Russisch sprechen.

and means

> She can speak Russian.

Therefore, the basic construction *kann*  does not appear as ungrammatical to native speakers of German. Using the construction with a noun that does not normally appear there will just look like a play on words, not like an error.

---

You asked whether

> Man muss Lied können.

is correct. While this kind of things always depends on context, under normal circumstances, it is not correct, as *Lied* cannot normally be used without an article (except when it is used to the effect of being a play on words on its own).

---

As for the meaning,

> Man muss Liebe können.

has rather a wider meaning than

> One has to be able to love.

While "being able to love" would probably refer only to one's capability of feeling and showing affection, the word "Liebe" in *Man muss Liebe können.* rather refers to all aspects of falling and being in love with someone, including not directly related aspects such as successfully managing to live together in one household, keeping the partner excited and happy about the relationship, or also identifying and getting in touch with the right partner in the first place<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup>: In short, everything that could make plot points in romantic comedy films, for which *Liebe muss man können.* sounds like an extremely typical tagline, and from which the film the OP mentioned might not be too far away, thematically.

Answer (score 1):

In a specialized context like real singing

> Lied muss man können

is correct. The context might be for instance

> Nächsten Monat haben die Sänger eine Prüfung. Oper und Oratorium können als erstes Stück gewählt werden. Der zweite Teil ist unbedingt Schubert. Denn *Lied muss man (als Sänger) können*.

Comment: I disagree. _Liebe_ doesn't need an article, but _Lied_ does.

Comment: @Iris: Not if it is used in a "musical concept" kind of way, like *Gesang*, *Schlagzeug*, or *Oper*. It is then a shortened way of saying something like "Das Thema *Lied* muss man können."

Comment: @Iris I would say that if you insert the article, *das Lied muss man können* would refer to a particular song. Not to the term *(deutsches) Lied*. But this is not my mother tongue, so I'm not highly confident here.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper, c.p. yes, you are right. _(Deutsches) Lied_ doesn't need an article.