# Warum darf "exponentiell" nicht auch als "exponenziell" geschrieben werden?

Tags: spelling, reformed-orthography

In der neuen Rechtschreibung werden viele Wörter, die früher mit "...tiell" geschrieben wurden, heute mit "...ziell" geschrieben, bzw. wird die Schreibweise mit "z" empfohlen, auch wenn die Schreibweise mit "t" noch erlaubt ist.

Beispielsweise ...

- [potenziell / potentiell](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/potenziell)
- [sequenziell / sequentiell](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sequenziell)
- [tendenziell](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/tendenziell)
- [substanziell / substantiell](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/substanziell)

Warum wird dann "exponentiell" ausschließlich mit "t" geschrieben und darf ([laut Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/exponentiell)) nicht als "exponenziell" geschrieben werden?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Die Schreibweise mit "z" ist darin begründet, dass die Endung der Adjektive zur Endung der zugehörigen Substantive passen soll.

Dementsprechend werden Begriffe wie "potenziell" (Potenz), "essenziell" (Essenz) oder "substanziell" (Substanz) mit der Endung "...ziell" geschrieben.

Wörter wie "exponentiell", die auf einem Begriff wie "Exponen**t**" aufbauen, werden hingegen mit "t" geschrieben und dürfen auch ausdrücklich nicht mit "z" geschrieben werden, anders als die obigen Begriffe, die gemäß der alten Rechtschreibung (noch) mit "t" geschrieben werden dürfen.

Quelle der Begründung, die in erster Linie als "richtig" erachtet wurde, weil es die einzige sinnvolle Begründung ist, die dazu gefunden wurde: https://web.archive.org/web/20170421220930/https://adremtext.ch/blog/tendenziell-oder-tendentiell

Comment: IQV  - Selbst wenn sich die Autoren der sogenannten neuen Rechtschreibung dies nicht aktiv selbst so gedacht haben sollten, die Begründung ist gut. Natürlich ist auch die Begründung, *substantiell* zu schreiben gut: Das zugrundeliegende Wort ist ja nicht eigentlich *Substanz*, sondern die lateinische *substantia*, und das z kam nur durch Zungenfaulheit rein.

Comment: der OP hat sich die Frage gestellt und ist während dem Schreiben der Frage auf [deren Antwort](https://adremtext.ch/blog/tendenziell-oder-tendentiell) gestoßen ^^
Das ist zwar keine offizielle Antwort einer an der Rechtschreibreform beteiligten Person (glaube ich), die Antwort ist aber soweit einleuchtend und sinnvoll. Entsprechend wollte ich die Frage nicht einfach löschen, sondern lieber mein neu erlangtes Wissen mit zukünftigen "Googlern" teilen :)

Comment: Die Sache mit *substanziell* aber nicht *exponenziell* ist übrigens eine schöne Illustration dafür, wo die sogenannte Rechtschreibreform mit dem idealistischen Bemühen, Schreibweisen logisch ableitbar zu machen, an einer verzwickten Wirklichkeit scheitert.

Comment: Schade, dass die Quelle nicht darauf eingeht, warum die Wörter denn früher mit *t* geschrieben wurden: Auch für die alten Schreibungen gibt es ja Ursachen. Und oft empfinden wir die alte Schreibung als falsch, weil der Grund für diese Schreibung in der heutigen Sprache nicht mehr (allzu) offensichtlich ist. (+1 für Kommentar von @ChristianGeiselmann)

Comment: Die Entscheidung, eine neue Schreibung einzuführen und eine alte Schreibung ungültig zu machen (oder nicht zu empfehlen) ist also ein bewusster Eingriff in die Schriftsprache (und natürlich wirkt sich das auf die gesprochene Sprache aus), und bedeutet, einen Teil der Sprachgeschichte „abzuschneiden“. Das reflektiert aber auch eine sprachliche Entwicklung, z. B. wenn sich der Literaturkanon einer Gesellschaft verändert. Irgendwas fällt hinten runter. Dafür traut man sich jetzt Präsident (https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/vorläufer-für-wer-traut-sich-jetzt-noch-präsident)

Comment: Wieso ist "Potenz" der Wortstamm und nicht "Potential"?

Comment: Das Beispiel mit potenziell ist unglücklich, da auch ["potentiell"](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/potenziell) richtig ist. Wie @userunknown schreibt gibt es auch die Schreibweise [Potential, was allerdings auch als Potenzial](http://www.rechtschreibtipps.de/potenzial.php) geschrieben werden kann. Wobei die Variante mit z die [zu bevorzugende](https://www.korrekturen.de/wortliste/potenziell.shtml) ist